# Defining atlas feature margin using PyQGIS3

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, print-composer, atlas

I want to create a simple atlas composer map using PyQGIS3. My question is about atlas feature scale. I want to use this settings from image.

[image]

I know this select option but I don't know how to add some number percent for margin in first option ( `layout.referenceMap().setAtlasScalingMode(QgsLayoutItemMap.Auto)` )

```
layout.referenceMap().setAtlasScalingMode(QgsLayoutItemMap.Auto)
layout.referenceMap().setAtlasScalingMode(QgsLayoutItemMap.Predefined)
layout.referenceMap().setAtlasScalingMode(QgsLayoutItemMap.Fixed)
```

Any idea how to do this in PyQGIS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at

```py
layout.referenceMap().atlasMargin(QgsLayoutObject.OriginalValue) # Get current value.
# You can replace above QgsLayoutObject.OriginalValue with QgsLayoutObject.EvaluatedValue
# if using an expression instead of a fixed value
layout.referenceMap().setAtlasMargin(yourvalue) # Set current value
```

Comment: how to get scale number from atlas feature after this code ?